# Are young Jedi more in tune with the Force than Sith and older Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force, sith

In many Star Wars films the Jedi are involved in a fight with a more skilled/experienced Sith and just before the Jedi is killed/defeated they suddenly remember the Force  and use it to improve their Lightsaber skills to win the fight.

This happens in Phantom Menace when Obi-Wan, a fairly untrained and young Jedi beats Darth Maul by using the Force to 'sense' how to defeat him. Darth Maul is clearly the better fighter as he defeated the experienced Qui-gon Jinn.

A similar thing happens in The Force Awakens when untrained Rey uses the Force to defeat skilled and experienced Kylo Ren.

Are these weaker, young Jedi more Force sensitive than the Sith and elder Jedi or is there some other reason?

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YouCantThwartStageOne?from=Main.EvilAlwaysTriumphsInTheMiddle

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NearVillainVictory

Comment: They made it obvious Kylo Ren was injured during his fight with Rey, due to being in the side by Chewie's blaster.  While still quite powerful, he was not up to full-strength, which Rey was able to take advantage of.  She was also shown to be capable of wielding a hand-to-hand weapon earlier in the film, so she wasn't entirely untrained (although certainly not experienced with a lightsaber).  As for Obi-Wan v Maul, I believe it was stated that Maul was caught completely off guard by Obi-Wan choosing to jump over him, which left him vulnerable to Obi-Wan's attack after he landed.

Comment: Obi-Wan was not "A fairly untrained and young Jedi" granted he was young but so was Darth Maul both of them had been trained since childhood now Maul probably was a more experienced fighter but Obi-Wan was very close to facing the trials ready to be a Jedi Knight I think a lot of people overlook the fact that Maul and Obi-Wan would have been close to the same age and probably had close to the same amount of training Maul's was simply more intense

Comment: Sith seek combat with any force user, Jedi or Sith. They will fight more duels, and more importantly, seek to dominate them via combat or Force augmented force of will. Obi-Wan if I recall, has mastered a very defensive lightsaber style. Maul? He's there to take heads. Qui-gon? Not so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from being an important trope - the villain needs to be a threat but also then overcome by the heroes - there is also the fact that all of these things are events that are guided by the force.

Remember - the force is not just a weapon or a tool, and the light and dark sides of the force are merely that, two sides of the same coin.

Connection with the force tends to grow stronger with age as the person matures and grows the patience to study and meditate upon the force and so allow it to shape their thinking, guide their actions and decisions. This is shown well in the way that we see Obi Wan develop over the years, from padawan to master to Old Ben.

The force isn't bias, it does not favour either jedi or sith, but rather it allows them both to prosper and grown and then be culled in order for the opposite side to flourish for a while because all things have their time, but that time is never forever.

Eventually, all things must come to an end and all force users must die, as is the will of the force, whether the wielder knows it or not. Some of the more powerful users have an inkling of when it is their time to go, such as Ben and Yoda.

In the instance of Darth Maul, he was a far better fighter than force user, as was shown in his approach to combat. Someone like Dooku however was simply overpowered by a far stronger force user, not because the jedi was younger but because the jedi was simply stronger and in his youth more physically in shape.

Comment: And don't forget over-confidence and arrogance, says Yoda: Yes. Yes. A flaw more and more common among Jedi. Too sure of themselves they are. Even the older, more experienced ones.

Answer (score 0):

Lets looks at some old Jedi and Sith:

Yoda is old, in fact Yoda is very old, yet is shown to be an extremely powerful force user.

Palpatine is also old yet he is shown besting every Jedi he fights.  As far as I know, he is undefeated in lightsaber combat.

To answer the question, I don't think younger Jedi are necessarily more powerful.